# Getting sub items using sql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have three tables,

`Entries`, `Tags`, `Entry_Tag_Link`

I have my query which goes through and pulls everything out of the `Entries` table

```
SELECT *
FROM (`blog_entries`)
ORDER BY `date` desc
```

I end up with an array of entries.

After that I loop through as

```
foreach($entries as &$entry)
    $entry['tags'] => getTags($entry['id]);
```

The `getTags` function runs this query

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM blog_tags t
JOIN blog_entries_tags_link l
    ON t.id = l.tag_id
WHERE l.entry_id = {whatever id was passed}
ORDER BY t.name asc;
```

So I end up with an array that looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => First Title
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => t1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => t2
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Second Title
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => t1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => t3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So, what it means is that I end up with 201 queries if there are 200 entries,
I am wondering if there is a way to get all the data I need in one query (and then assumedly massage it into the correct format with php)?

Comment: maybe try to use l.entry_id IN (entry1, entry2....), that way you dont have to do one by one, but all of them in one query.

Comment: Can you please post the table structure and what your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your blog entry id is blog_entry_id...

Request :

```
SELECT b.title, t.entry_id, t.name, l.tag_id 
FROM blog_entries b
JOIN blog_tags t on t.entry_id = b.blog_entry_id
JOIN blog_entries_tags_link l on t.id = l.tag_id
ORDER BY b.date DESC, t.name ASC
```

PHP :

```
$result = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {

    // Creates a new blog entry on the $result array
    if (!isset($result[ $entry['entry_id'] ])) {
        $blog_entry = array();
        $blog_entry['id'] = $entry['entry_id'];
        $blog_entry['title'] = $entry['title'];
        $blog_entry['tags'] = array();
        $result[ $entry['entry_id'] ] = $entry;
    }

    // Add a new tag
    $tag = array();
    $tag['id'] = $entry['tag_id'];
    $tag['name'] = $entry['name'];
    $result[ $entry['entry_id'] ]['tags'][] = $tag;

}
```

You may note that you never use blog_entry_tags_link (I am using it just because I do not know your column names).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, at least from the SQL perspective.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM blog_tags t join
     blog_entries_tags_link l
     ON t.id = l.tag_id join
     (SELECT *
      FROM `blog_entries` e
     ) e
     on l.entry_id = e.entry_id
WHERE l.entry_id = {whatever id was passed}
ORDER BY e.`date` desc, t.name asc
```

This is assuming that the id is unique for each blog_entry (and your code suggests this is the case).

Comment: So this query should return One row for every tag link in the database yes? I would then loop over the results and create an array in the format I wish?

Comment: Yes . . . You can then load it into the appropriate data structure in php.  Getting all the results in a single query should perform much better than running a separate query for each row.